# Sprintf() cannot accept function parameter

Tags: c, printf

I want to write a program like this to let sprintf() accept the function parameter

```
int x (char z) { //z is a character array
    float y = 10.254;
    sprintf (z, "%2.1f", y);
    printf ("%c", &z);
}
```

However when I enter the array as a parameter, nothing happens.

How can I let sprintf accept an external parameter

Comment: z is not a character array.

Comment: `char* z` no? use `snprintf()` instead of just `sprintf()`; that requires buffer length to be passed to the function `x()`

Comment: You should see an error message for `sprintf (z, "%2.1f", y);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char z` is just a single character. nothing more

`char* z` is usually understood to be a string or a buffer capable of holding a string (or more precisely, a pointer to a character)

`%c` is the format specifier for a single char. `%s` is for a null terminated char array (or char*)

This is closer to what you want:

```
int x (char* z) { 
    float y = 10.254;
    sprintf (z, "%2.1f", y);
    printf ("%s", z);
}
```

Then invoke:

```
char buffer[100]; // big enough
x(buffer);
```

Comment: better is to pass the length as an argument and use snprintf, this code is just asking for trouble otherwise. Also it doesnt return an int